# "had X a..." vs "was X having a..."

Tags: questions, progressive-aspect, do-support

What's the difference between the two? Example:

> The classrooms had only students. Had the school a shortage of
>   teachers?
>
> The classrooms had only students. Was the school having a shortage of
>   teachers?

(Or maybe one of them is ungrammatical?)

Comment: The first version is now outdated., but would once have been acceptable.  The second version is much better for the modern world.

Comment: "*Had* the teachers gone on strike?" is an example of common inversion with the auxiliary; but as StoneyB and WadCheber say, when "had" is the lexical verb and not a helper to form the perfect, you won't see inversion nowadays.  And we  might also use dummy 'there' to reinforce the idea of ongoing state: "Was there a shortage of teachers at the school?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The progressive expresses a continuing state rather than an event, so we ordinarily do not use verbs whose meaning designates a state in the progressive. It's superfluous.

*Have* is freely used in the progressive when it expresses an event (*I'm having some people over tonight.* or *I'll have my secretary send it to you.*), but in your example it expresses the state of undergoing a shortage. We would use the progressive, *Was the school having a shortage?*, only to suggest that we had a *temporary* shortage in mind.

Note, by the way, that the practice of inverting *have* with its subject in questions when it is not used as the perfect auxiliary has become quite rare, even in British English; it has virtually vanished from American English. Most people today would say

> ***Did*** the school ***have*** a shortage of teachers?